# How to sync data on two hard drives?

Tags: windows, hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Keeping folders synced between several machines](https://superuser.com/questions/349/keeping-folders-synced-between-several-machines)
>   [Synchronize Laptop and Desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/64526/synchronize-laptop-and-desktop)
>   [Which is the best application to Sync two folders?](https://superuser.com/questions/13493/which-is-the-best-application-to-sync-two-folders)

That's it. What can I use to keep my hard drives in sync on Windows?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/65025/best-way-to-sync-two-computers http://superuser.com/questions/64526/synchronize-laptop-and-desktop http://superuser.com/questions/13493/which-is-the-best-application-to-sync-two-folders

Answer (score 1):

I do it this way,

make a file called sync.bat

```
XCOPY t:\somefiles f:\copy /D /I /S /C /Y
XCOPY f:\copy t:\sometimes /D /I /S /C /Y
```

XCOPY copies files from one directory to another, and then the options I set do the following; assume it's a directory, copy the newer files, overwrite the older files, and don't ask if I want to write over it every time.