# Backup software that allows to synchronize modified documents between two computers?

Tags: windows-7, backup, sync, documents

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Synchronize Laptop and Desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/64526/synchronize-laptop-and-desktop)

I have two computers running on windows, one at work and one at home, I take a copy of the documents that I work on to home and keep working on them when I'm home. So my problem is that I need a software to backup these documents for me on my **external hard** at the end of the day at work and when I take it home I can synchronize my documents with it, so I'll have the same modifications on my documents at **home** as I have done at **work**.

appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Synctoy](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15155) if you want to keep two distinct file stores.

But also consider using free cloud storage, such as [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/home), [Skydrive](https://skydrive.live.com/) or [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/). If you can install these at work (not always possible), they seem a more seamless option.

Answer (score 1):

[Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/)

But there must be an existing identical Q  ...